# Cannot deploy Grails app on Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, grails

I cannot deploy my Grails 2.2.4 application on my Tomcat 6. I've tried fresh installation of tomcat and even the old version of my application (which was running before).

This exception is thrown after one min. after the tomcat starts:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList.cursor(CursorableLinkedList.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:1536)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1749)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/CursorableLinkedList$Cursor
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList.cursor(CursorableLinkedList.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:1536)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1749)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 5 more
Oct 24, 2013 8:34:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore.keySet(CompoundStore.java:216)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.factories.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I really have no clue where to start to fix it. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You should add `commons-pool-1.4.jar` to you application with `runtime` scope.
Add

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   // ...  
   dependencies {
        // ...
        runtime 'commons-pool:commons-pool:1.4'
   }
   // ...
}
```

to project file `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

Read more in [**Grails: Dependency Resolution**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution)

Comment: This doesn't help. Anyway when I run dependency-report command I see that I have this dependency in my project. Could it be something with file permissions on the server or Grails Migration or Quartz job which I use in the project? I really don't know where to start...

Comment: @user607038 observe your grails application (`war` file). Do you have `commons-pool` in lib folder?

Comment: It is there, most weird is that the app runs on a different tomcat of the same machine. I think this could be some permission problem...

Comment: @user607038 You can try to put `commons-pool` to Tomcat's lib folder